# python script unable to call fn in other python scripts hosted on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, discord, discord.py

Ive made a Discord Bot using Python and hosted the same on Heroku using built in Git commands. It runs the main script i.e DiscordBot.py, this script calls another fn topGainer from topGainer.py

When i run the DiscordBot.py locally on my system the bot functions perfectly but on Heroku it is unable to call topGainer .py The Function topGainer returns a list made with Tabulate

Here is the code for discord bot

```
if message.author == client.user:
    return

if message.content.startswith('$gainer'):
    tg=topGainer()
    await message.channel.send(tg)
    
if message.content.startswith('$loser'):
    tl=topLoser()
    await message.channel.send(tl)
    
if message.content.startswith('$get'):
    scrip = msg.split("$get ",1)[1]
    info=basic(scrip)
    await message.channel.send(info)
    
if message.content.startswith('$AnotherFunction'):
    await message.channel.send('Coming Soon :')
```

Also in the Heroku Procfile i have `worker: python DiscordBot.py`

On heroku this code does login on the discord bot and the function $AnotherFunction works.

Comment: Did you mean "unable to call functions from other python files"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku is notoriously bad at hosting discord bots for a multitude of reasons. I would recommend using a different host (AWS offers a year free hosting) due to the fact that one of the main people who made discord.py(Danny) has said not to use it. [image: Why Herkou is bad for discord bots]

> - Also Bots are not what the platform is designed for. Heroku is designed to provide web servers (like Django, Flask, etc). This is why they give you a domain name and open a port on their local emulator. (Referenced from the discord.py discord server)

Heroku could be what is causing your error if it runs perfect locally.

Comment: Thanks Harry will give aws a shot. I've been wondering what's wrong with the code

Comment: For sure, if you need a link to a tutorial on how to set it up. [AWS support](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/free-tier-windows-instance/)